# numpy genfromtxt converters not working with unicode (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, unicode

I am moving some code from Python2 to Python3.

I am aware of the whole "unicode" vs. "bytes" change that affects how strings are handled (unicode by default in Python 3).

However, I am finding some inconsistencies in how numpy is handling them in the `converters` callback on the `genfromtxt` function.

Consider the data file (data.txt):

```
1,2,hello!
3,4,world!
```

I want to read in the strings and remove the "!" with a covnerter. In Python 2 I did this:

```
np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', dtype='i4,i4,S10',
        converters={2:lambda s: s.strip('!')})
```

which works fine. For Python 3, I simply changed the S10 to U10 in the dtypes  to ensure that the data is read in as unicode and not a byte array:

```
np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', dtype='i4,i4,U10',
        converters={2:lambda s: s.strip('!')})
```

However, the converter fails with the error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

It seems the converter funtion is still receiving a byte array, not a unicode string, as the only way to get it to work is to change `s.strip('!')` to `s.strip(b'!')`

This seems inconsistent to me. Especially as it works fine if I perform the strip command **AFTER** I read the array, rather than as a converter, i.e. this works fine:

```
dat=np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', dtype='i4,i4,U10') 
print(dat.dtype)
print(dat['f2'][0].strip('!') # notice, no 'b' needed
```

prints:

```
[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<U10')]
hello
```

This seems inconsistent to me and is making it difficult to know when to use the 'b' specifier to avoid the aforementioned error!

Im finding the whole unicode vs. bytes issue very frustrating in Python 3!

Comment: What exactly is your question? This sounds more like a bug report for the Numpy project, and fairly valid one at that

Comment: Is supose my question is: am I missing sometihng or doing something wrong? (I usually am....)

Comment: I suspect this is simply a quirck of numpy reading everyting in as bytes (in c-code I presume), which used to work fine with legacy python's `str` type, but now causes a type-mismatch because bytes in python 3 are treated differently than unicode strings. I would submit this to the issue tracker for numpy

Comment: Thanks @Energya - will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the opening mode of the file.  For compatibility with Py2, `genfromtxt` used to always operate in the byte mode.  Now Py3 can open it in 'text' mode

Adding the `encoding` parameter (here `None` is enough, the file is saved as UTF8):

```
In [373]: np.genfromtxt('stack54570492.txt', delimiter=',', dtype='i4,i4,S10',
     ...:         converters={2:lambda s: s.strip('!')}, encoding=None)     
Out[373]: 
array([(1, 2, b'hello'), (3, 4, b'world')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', 'S10')])
```

(See the docs for more details on this parameter.)

The converter is applied to the 'raw' string, before there's any attempt to assign `dtype`.  So it doesn't matter whether you specified `U10` or `S10`.  Often a converter used to clean up a string so it can be converted to a number.

In your post processing case the `b` is still needed - depending on the dtype:

```
In [376]: dat=np.genfromtxt('stack54570492.txt', delimiter=',', dtype='i4,i4,S10')
In [377]: dat
Out[377]: 
array([(1, 2, b'hello!'), (3, 4, b'world!')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', 'S10')])
In [378]: dat['f2'][0].strip('!')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-378-697f391eaffc> in <module>()
----> 1 dat['f2'][0].strip('!')

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
In [379]: dat['f2'][0].strip(b'!')
Out[379]: b'hello'
```

Full help for `encoding`:

> encoding : str, optional
>
> Encoding used to decode the inputfile. Does not apply when `fname` is
>       a file object.  The special value 'bytes' enables backward compatibility
>       workarounds that ensure that you receive byte arrays when possible
>       and passes latin1 encoded strings to converters. Override this value to
>       receive unicode arrays and pass strings as input to converters.  If set
>       to None the system default is used. The default value is 'bytes'.
>
> .. versionadded:: 1.14.0

With the 'bytes' encoding, the `b'!'` is required in the converter (regardless of specified dtype):

```
In [382]: np.genfromtxt('stack54570492.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=None,
     ...:         converters={2:lambda s: s.strip(b'!')}, encoding='bytes')      
Out[382]: 
array([(1, 2, b'hello'), (3, 4, b'world')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', 'S5')])

In [383]: np.genfromtxt('stack54570492.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=None,
     ...:         converters={2:lambda s: s.strip('!')}, encoding=None)
Out[383]: 
array([(1, 2, 'hello'), (3, 4, 'world')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<U5')])
```